# MQSeries CSIException: JMSCS0002 but classpath looks ok for commonservices

Tags: ibm-mq

In trying to connect from an MQSeries 7.5 client to a 7.5 local server I'm getting a CSIException: JMSCS0002 which when I look up the error in the IBM codes says:

JMSCS0002 
The call could not be completed because CommonServices has not been initialized.

CommonServices is an internal component and needs to be initialized at startup but has failed.

Check that the installation and classpath setup is correct.

But both my compile and run classpaths include com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar, com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.jar, and com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.jar

I'm was using Oracle JDK 1.6. I tried using the WS MQ java but it made no difference.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

```
 Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.CSIException: JMSCS0002
at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.PIWorkQueueManager.enqueueItem(PIWorkQueueManager.java:67)
at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.enqueue(WorkQueueManager.java:225)
at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.enqueue(WorkQueueManager.java:194)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.WMQThreadPool.enqueue(WMQThreadPool.java:91)
```

Comment: Answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39413916/jmscs0002-from-spring-jms-and-ibm-websphere-mq/43367100#43367100) might be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had been using jar files from an uninstalled MQSeries 7.5 Client because I wanted to make sure that the functionality I was using would work just with the jars provided by the free client license. According to IBM documentation taking uninstalled jars is problematic.

When I switched to the jars from the installed server trial then things works ok.

Comment: same for me, so this fixed it for me as well.

Comment: I was having the same issue thanks, the jars can be found inside your IBM\WebSphereMQ\java\lib folder.

Comment: I think this software's warn message is not enough in detal, actually i forget to set com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.jar to lib, but the warning msg is JMSCS0002.