# JMSCS0002 from Spring JMS and IBM Websphere MQ

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jar, ibm-mq

I've seen a question or two on Stack overflow regarding this error but I'm still unable to solve it, so I thought I would pose my own question.

Here's my issue:

I'm using Spring and Spring's JMSTemplate to do some messaging and queue work. I'm trying to read from a queue. I'm not 100% positive if my logic is correct in my code, but anytime I try to run my app I am greeted with this exception (I've included only the last section):

```
Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.CSIException: JMSCS0002
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.PIWorkQueueManager.enqueueItem(PIWorkQueueManager.java:67)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.enqueue(WorkQueueManager.java:225)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.enqueue(WorkQueueManager.java:194)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.WMQThreadPool.enqueue(WMQThreadPool.java:91)
```

Now I'm fairly certain this has nothing to do with my code because no matter how much I change my logic, if I try calling any of the methods made available by `JMSTemplate`, I receive this exception. After doing some research (based on the other stack overflow answers) I assume it has something to do with the way my classpath is setup. Here is a link to those questions:

[One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639212/mqseries-csiexception-jmscs0002-but-classpath-looks-ok-for-commonservices) and [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36849774/ibm-mq-ffdc-csiexception-jmscs0002-when-i-try-to-run-from-console)

In addition to this, here's some info I found on IBM's [site](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/jm10330_.htm):

> To compile and run WebSphere MQ classes for JMS applications, use the
>   CLASSPATH setting for your platform as shown in Table 1.
>
> CLASSPATH=MQ_INSTALLATION_PATH\java\lib\com.ibm.mqjms.jar;
>   MQ_INSTALLATION_PATH\tools\jms;

I have tried this however and It still seems to be failing me. Here's what I have added in my .bat file for my application that I run:

`c:\java\jre6\bin\javaw -cp "C:\ussco\wmsflgint\mqs\mqjms-7.5.0.0.jar; C:\ussco\wmsflgint\mqs\mq-7.5.0.0.jar; C:\ussco\wmsflgint\mqs\headers-1.4.2.jar; C:\ussco\wmsflgint\mqs\jmqi-7.5.0.0.jar;" -Xmx256M ....` (there's more on the end but I don't feel it's relevant)

Am I not adding this correctly?

Thanks

Comment: I think you are missing com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar in your class path. Try adding this jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you have been copying and renaming IBM MQ jar files and, as a result, do not have the full set on the Java class path at runtime.  This can lead to all kinds problems and unexpected exceptions, such as the one you are experiencing.

Please note that copying MQ jar files, renaming them and/or bundling them into applications is not permitted by IBM Support and invalidates the MQ terms and conditions. (The rules are subtlety different for bundling into apps for the V8 and V9 redistributable client and allclient; but your not using that here).

If you perform a proper install of the MQ client onto your system (which you should do) and then use the instructions that you have already found in the Knowledge Center to reference the com.ibm.mq.jar file for classes for Java applications or the com.ibm.mqjms.jar for classes for JMS applications on the Java class path, your problem will be resolved.

Comment: Okay so I updated my classpath to: `-cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\java\lib\com.ibm.mqjms.jar" "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\java\lib\com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar"; "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\tools\jms"; ` and now I receive error: `Cannot find main class C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\java\lib\com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar`

Comment: Hi.  You haven't configured your class path correctly because you have a space between the entries. For reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html Regardless, why have you explicitly added the com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar file to the class path when this is not necessary and not mentioned in the IBM MQ KC pages?

Comment: I edited it to: `c:\java\jre6\bin\javaw -cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\java\lib\com.ibm.mqjms.jar"; ` as listed in the IBM MQ Pages but i am still receiving this exception. No spaces because no other jars are needed according to IBM

Answer (score 4):

I've just ran into the same issue with queue listeners. The solution was to place a file compinfo.properties under the directory src/main/resources/META-INF of the Spring project. The file should set values for two properties:

```
CompList: comp1
comp1_CompClass: com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.J2SEComponent
```

Or you can change the property (**comp1_CompClass**) value right in the jar **com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.jar**. It has the same effect though I doubt it's legal due to copyright. 
Hope it would be helpful and save a couple of hours for someone.

Comment: Worked for me! Got the problem while upgrading from 7.1.0.7 to 7.5.0.4 and repackaging the jars from the rar file, which also contains a `compinfo.properties` file with other values for these properties. Where did you get the info?

Comment: I accidentally found the solution in VCS history. Then I'd tried to find more meaningful explanation on the internet but had no success.